# How to add / remove / edit value of kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObject

Tags: kotlin, jetbrains-ide, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I am currently struggling for best way to add property to existing `jsonObject(kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObject)`

Even I have found that JsonObject internally has private immutable map

```
private val content: Map<String, JsonElement>
```

**Scenario:** Suppose I already have one `jsonObject` with 50 properties in it and considering jsonObject at any key can have any number of depth.

For such situation how can we efficiently perform below operations:

> 1. Adding primitive properties
> 2. Updating primitive properties
> 3. Deleting primitive properties

**FYI :** Even I have found there is class called **JsonObjectBuilder** but it does not take existing JsonElement / JsonObject / JsonArray infact it will newly create another jsonObject.

Thanks for giving your time to read till here

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1593

Answer (score 15):

Since this internal `content` map is immutable, the only way to edit `JsonObject` is to create new one (out of old). Luckily, there is a `JsonObject` constructor taking a `Map`, moreover `JsonObject` implements the `Map` interface itself. So I'd suggest the following idiom:

```kotlin
val newJsonObj = JsonObject(oldJsonObj.toMutableMap().apply {
    // edit like ordinary mutable map
})
```

Comment: Thanks for helping as of now i have created this extension function https://gist.github.com/MeNiks/597b761f3b2ea8ec511d5d40a3213399

Comment: Will that copy the entire content of the json?

Comment: @MaksimGayduk, yes this call is delegated to internal `content` map itself